# How to get country name

Tags: c#-4.0, globalization, cultureinfo, country

I used the code below to get the list of culture type, is there a way on how to get just the country name?

Thank you

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
    {
        sb.Append(ci.DisplayName);
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Sample Output:**

Spanish (Puerto Rico)

Spanish (United States)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this regular expression seems to do the job in most cases:

```cs
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"([\w+\s*\.*]+\))");
foreach (var item in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
{
    var match = regex.Match(item.DisplayName);
    string countryName = match.Value.Length == 0 ? "NA" : match.Value.Substring(0, match.Value.Length - 1);
    Console.WriteLine(countryName);
}
```

Comment: DisplayName gives names like "German", "Catalan", "Finnish" etc. These are not exactly country names. Otherwise, we may use DisplayName or EnglishName.

Comment: In most cases DisplayName includes the country/region name surrounded by parenthesis, it's this last portion that we are getting with the regular expression. A bit of hack, but it works :-)

Comment: Display name is not a country

Answer (score 54):

You can use the Name property of the CultureInfo to construct a RegionInfo. You can then use the DisplayName property.
Try:

```cs
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
{
    var ri = new RegionInfo(ci.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(ri.DisplayName);
}
```

Comment: You should use **`new RegionInfo(ci.LCID)`**, it's faster. Source: decompiler. Links on the MSDN: [CultureInfo.LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid(v=vs.80).aspx) and [RegionInfo constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ftdh74h(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Be aware of using LCID if you have custom cultures - they all have LCID = 4096.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Build your normal dictionary as container
Dictionary<string, string> countryNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
{
    RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(ci.Name);
    // Check if the ISO language code is already in your collection 
    // Because you don't want double entries in a country box because we had to use the culture info
    if (!countryNames.ContainsKey(ri.TwoLetterISORegionName))
    {
        countryNames.Add(ri.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToUpper(), ri.EnglishName);
    }
}
// Code for dictionary to dropdownlist transform can be written with your personal preference for symantics 
SelectList countryDropdown = new SelectList(countryNames.OrderBy(o => o.Value), "Key", "Value");
```

Or ready for use without comments:

```
Dictionary<string, string> countryNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
{
    RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(ci.Name);
    if (!countryNames.ContainsKey(ri.TwoLetterISORegionName)) countryNames.Add(ri.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToUpper(), ri.EnglishName);
}
SelectList countryDropdown = new SelectList(countryNames.OrderBy(o => o.Value), "Key", "Value");
```

Comment: Using `Keys.ToList().Contains()` is a bad idea since it makes the algorithm O(n^2). Why not just use `containsKey()`?

Answer (score 0):

this would be what you are looking for:

```cs
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
{
    sb.Append(ci.EnglishName);
    sb.AppendLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use following namespaces

```cs
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Globalization;       

/// <summary>
/// populate country name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dropDown"></param>
public static void GetCountryNames(DropDownList dropDown)
{
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    Dictionary<string, string> objDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (CultureInfo ObjCultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
    {
        RegionInfo objRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(ObjCultureInfo.Name);
        if (!objDic.ContainsKey(objRegionInfo.EnglishName))
        {
            objDic.Add(objRegionInfo.EnglishName, objRegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToLower());
        }
    }

    SortedList<string, string> sortedList = new SortedList<string, string>(objDic);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in sortedList)
    {
        dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(val.Key, val.Key));
    }

    dropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "Select"));
    dropDown.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Other Country", "Other"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my nuget package [`Nager.Country`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Country). There is a lot of additional information available for each country. For more information please visit the [Github project](https://github.com/nager/Nager.Country)

```
PM> install-package Nager.Country
```

```cs
ICountryProvider countryProvider = new CountryProvider();
foreach (var countryCode in (Alpha2Code[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Alpha2Code)))
{
    var countryInfo = countryProvider.GetCountry(countryCode);
    Console.WriteLine(countryInfo.CommonName);
}
```