# How to get the country code from CultureInfo?

Tags: c#, globalization

I have the following:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo c = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");

var a = c.DisplayName;
var b = c.EnglishName;
var d = c.LCID;
var e = c.Name;
var f = c.NativeName;
var g = c.TextInfo;
var h = c.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName;
var i = c.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName;
var j = c.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

None of this gives me the country code, e.g. `GB`.

Is there a way to get it without string splitting?

Comment: Isn't `TwoLetterISOLanguageName`?

Comment: Maybe you're not looking for a [culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but for a [region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Alberto that would be `en`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87k6sx8t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [.Net - CultureInfo: How to get country name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655738/net-cultureinfo-how-to-get-country-name)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: While related, not an exact duplicate. The other question looks for a human-readable country name, this one is about a region code. In particular, the selected solution to the other question is not applicable here.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Wrong duplicate

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: wrong mean using `DisplayName` instead `Name`?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Yes, It is about country name, here question is about country code. Not exact duplicate, but that's related one.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
var c = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
var r = new RegionInfo(c.LCID);
string name = r.Name;
```

Most probably you need to use `r.TwoLetterISORegionName` property.

```
string regionName = r.TwoLetterISORegionName;
```

Comment: Note: You should check CultureInfo.IsNeutralCulture before feeding its LCID to RegionInfo. RegionInfos cannot be created from Neutral cultures (eg "en").

Comment: Instead of new RegionInfo(c.LCID) it is better to use new RegionInfo(c.ToString()); because multiple cultures have the same LCID, e.g. both "en-GG" (Guernsey) and "en-JE" (Jersey) have an LCID of 4096

Answer (score 12):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo c = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
var ri = new RegionInfo(c.Name);
string countryName = ri.DisplayName;
```

That will give you:

```
"United Kingdom"
```

For Two Letter Use:

```
string countryAbbrivation = ri.TwoLetterISORegionName;
```

That will give you "GB"

Comment: He wanted "GB" - you gave him "United Kingdom". This might help him but isn't what was asked for...

Comment: @Chris, `string countryAbbrivation = ri.TwoLetterISORegionName;` would do it. added in the answer as well

Answer (score 6):

You can try the [**RegionInfo Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.RegionInfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). One of the properties is the [**RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.twoletterisoregionname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Example from MSDN:

```
RegionInfo myRI1 = new RegionInfo("US");
Console.WriteLine( "   Name:                         {0}", myRI1.Name );
Console.WriteLine( "   ThreeLetterISORegionName:     {0}", myRI1.ThreeLetterISORegionName );
Console.WriteLine( "   TwoLetterISORegionName:       {0}", myRI1.TwoLetterISORegionName );
```

> Name:                         US
>
> ThreeLetterISORegionName:     USA
>
> TwoLetterISORegionName:       US

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to use the `RegionInfo` of the current thread, you can get the country code with this one-liner:

```cs
RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will also accept CultureInfo("en");

```
var c = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
string countryAbbrivation;
if (!c.IsNeutralCulture) 
{
                    var region = new RegionInfo(ContentLanguage.PreferredCulture.LCID);
                    countryAbbrivation = region.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToLower();
}else{
                    countryAbbrivation = c.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of answers on this thread, I created a static helper that returns the region/culture CountryCode:

```
public static class CultureInfoExtensions {
    public static string GetCultureCountryCode(this CultureInfo culture) {
        return (culture.IsNeutralCulture == false)
            ? new RegionInfo(culture.LCID).TwoLetterISORegionName
            : culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
    }
}
```