# How to get "UK" from CultureInfo in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get the value UK (or the equivalent value for another country) from C# CultureInfo object?  My example below shows I currently get "United Kingdon" using the following line of code.

```
var region = new RegionInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID)
```

**Update the comments**

After receiving really great help I want to clarify my problem.  I need to provide the value "UK" based on the locale settings.  I currently have the following values

```
locale_country: "United Kingdom"  // This needs to be UK (or the equivalent for another country)
locale_language: "en-GB"
locale_region: "GB"
```

The code that generates this is illustrated below (C#)

**Code snippet**

```
var localRegion = new RegionInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
LocaleRegion = localRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName,
LocaleCountry = localRegion.DisplayName
```

Comment: region.name may work. Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330343/how-to-get-the-country-code-from-cultureinfo

Comment: Question title says *how to get **GB***. Question body says *is it possible to get value **UK***. I suppose title is wrong

Comment: The value is used for our website tracking digital data variable on the page.  The requirement for the tracking to work when browsing the UK variant of our website to populate a property within the tracking object called locale_country to equal "uk" - does that help?

Comment: apologies - I've corrected the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName` returns the 2-letter country code as defined by ISO-3166.

[ISO-3166](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html) defines the United Kingdom to have the country code `"GB"` not `"UK"`.

Comment: really sorry, I got confused, my requirement is retrieve the value "uk"

Comment: You cannot do this using RegionInfo, as UK is not part of ISO-3166.  You would have to use a little logic to change it to UK if the received value was GB.

Comment: okay thank you.  I'll get on that now

Answer (score 7):

Following code should work :

```
var cul = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
var regn = new RegionInfo(cul.LCID);
string name = regn.TwoLetterISORegionName;
```

Comment: it returns "GB"

Comment: Sorry , Please use CultureIfo as "uk-UA". it might be a work around for getting UK.

Comment: It needs to be dynamic obviously, I'm just using UK as an example to see if it produces the desired result

Comment: So, what is the specification for your expected country codes?