# How to get current local user with System.Globalization?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm making a system about seasons and I need to get a user's location to discover the current hemisphere.
So I find System.Globalization namespace, but I don't know the correct property for that.

Comment: If you know the users time zone, then you can get the hemisphere. What kind of app is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no methods in `System.Globalization` to get user's location to obtain information you are looking for.

You can (in reverse order of precision)

- get precise location using corresponding location API - i.e. [Geolocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator?view=winrt-18362) for UWP app.
- map user's IP to a ZIP code/city level location - [Get user location by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327629/get-user-location-by-ip-address)
- writing  custom code that maps user's preferred country code to data you need starting from `System.Globablization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` - [How to get the country code from CultureInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330343/how-to-get-the-country-code-from-cultureinfo)